# Authorize for all Gets on webApi NetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, webapi

I don't know if it's possible, but, could I make something like a default policy for all my GET actions in my webApi, so they require a especific role, one for "read", "write" and "delete".

Not putting a [Authorize()] in each action of a component, more like a policy in the AddAuthorization of the StartUp.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know if it's possible, but, could I make something like a
> default policy for all my GET actions in my webApi, so they require a
> especific role, one for "read", "write" and "delete".

Yes, you can use the Policy-based authorization with Role-based authorization.

> Not putting a [Authorize()] in each action of a component, more like a
> policy in the AddAuthorization of the StartUp.

The `services.AddAuthorization()` method in the Startup.ConfigureServices method is used to **define the policies**, after that the policies are **applied to controllers** by using the **[Authorize]** attribute with the policy name.

Here is a sample about using the Policy-based authorization with Role-based authorization in Asp.net Core MVC, you could refer it.

1. Create an ASP.NET MVC Core Application (using Individual User Accounts Authentication).
2. Using migration to generate the Identity User tables.
3. Click on the project and select add, then add a scaffolding item and select Identity, select Override all files, and Add the Identity Template pages.
4. Create a view and controller for the Roles:

   ```
    public class RoleController : Controller
    {
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

        public RoleController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            this.roleManager = roleManager;
        } 
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var roles = roleManager.Roles.ToList();
            return View(roles);
        } 
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(new IdentityRole());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(IdentityRole role)
        {
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
   ```

   using RoleManager to manage roles, add related views.

   modify the Startup.cs files, as shown below:

   ```
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
             .AddDefaultUI()
             .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
             .AddDefaultTokenProviders(); 

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
   ```

   In the Register page, you could add a property to let use select the Role, and use the UserManager.AddToRoleAsync() method to add roles for user.

   After that, we could create roles suing the RoleController, like this:

   [image]
5. Configure Authentication: define he following policies in ConfigureServices:

   ```
        services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("readpolicy",
                builder => builder.RequireRole("Admin", "Manager", "User"));
            options.AddPolicy("writepolicy",
                builder => builder.RequireRole("Admin", "Manager"));
        });
   ```

   Then, you could apply these policies to the Controller or Action method.

   ```
        [Authorize(Policy = "readpolicy")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var roles = roleManager.Roles.ToList();
            return View(roles);
        }
        //[Authorize(Policy = "writepolicy")]
        [Authorize(Roles ="User")]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(new IdentityRole());
        }
   ```

   After that, if current user role doesn't have access to the related action method, it will show the "Access denied":

   [image]

Reference:

[Adding Role Authorization to a ASP.NET MVC Core Application](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-role-authorization-to-a-asp-net-mvc-core-application/)

[Policy-Based And Role-Based Authorization In ASP.NET Core 3.0 Using Custom Handler](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/policy-based-role-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core/)

[Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Well, it was a good explanation of policies, but it wasn't what I was searching for, I wanted something generic for all the calls with the attribute Get (example) but also it should be applied directly in startup for everyone instead of puting the authorize in every Call/Action, I suppose it can't be done. Anyways, I went with this approach. Thank you.